# Computation of temperature using Temp Sensor Lm35 with LPC1768

Tags: temperature, sensors

I have connected a LM35 to ADC channel 1 of LPC1768. getting a value of 306(adc reading).

```
Vref =5V
```

For 12 bit ADC

```
Step size = 5V/4096=1.22mV
```

to calculate the output voltage.

```
Vout in mV = adc_reading * Step size = 306 * 1.22mV= 373.32mV
```

LM35 sensor gives an output of 10mV for every 1 degree centigrade. so the measured temperature is

```
373.32/10= 37 degree centigrade
```

But Bangalore's temperature reading is 27 degree centigrade.

Refering to [Mazidi's "AVR Microcontroller and Embedded Systems" book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0138003319), The digital output from ADC is calculated by the below formula

```
Vout = analog input voltage/step size
```

If Vout is calculated with the above formula then o/p voltage is

```
Vout = 306/1.22=250.819mV
```

Voltage to temperature conversion = 250.819mV/10mV = 25.08 degree centigrade.

Unable to figure out what is right. Kindly help. Sorry for this silly question.

Also connected an LDR to ADC channel 0 of LPC1768. Calculated the measured output voltage

```
Vout = adc_reading*step size.

for adc_reading = 55-> vout = 0.064713

adc_reading = 3245-> vout = 3.962149

adc_reading = 4095-> vout = 4.999995
```

May be you experts can throw some light on this. Confused as to why i am unable to get the right temperature as per my city.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was using 5V as VCC instead of 3V3. Now getting the right temperature.